# Skip "Installing dependencies with npm" step when pushing a Node.js app to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

Running `git push heroku master` always triggers a step that prompts:

> Installing dependencies with npm

This step loads and reinstalls all of the dependencies again even it already exists. This is very time consuming and I want to skip this step sometimes when I deploy that I know the dependencies are the same.

Is there any command or options that do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, if you take a look at the [Heroku buildpack for node.js](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/compile#L171), there doesn't appear to a skip `npm install` option. It always runs `npm install --production` followed by `npm rebuild`. It is possible, however, to create your [own buildpack on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) that specifies a different behavior for `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

Its been a long time since you asked this question, now the Heroku buildpack caches `node_modules`, so install times will be much faster.

If however you still want to block `npm install`, here is one solution.

As of when I write this, the default Heroku build pack does not allow skipping npm install entirely. You can see in the [dependencies.sh](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/lib/dependencies.sh) file, this line will always run:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm --userconfig $build_dir/.npmrc 2>&1
```

However, if you create a file called `.npmrc` in your project folder with the following contents:

```
dry-run
```

This will cause npm install to not modify your existing `node_modules` directory.

Note that this change will also apply to the `npm prune` command that Heroku runs, but *WILL NOT* apply to the `npm rebuild` command (which is probably fine).

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

> node_modules

for example
from you .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Simplest ways I've found are

> heroku apps:rename newTemporaryName

then

> heroku apps:rename originalName

or change the NODE_ENV and get it back to previous again.

> heroku config:set NODE_ENV=dev

then

> heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production

There are probably other, similar hacks but these should be sufficient.